# retrieve all possible substring matches with n characters from a string

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

Basically I want to retrieve all possible substring matches with n characters from a string, Here's my initial code but it only returns 2 matches.

```
String input = "abc12345abcd";
Regex  regex = new Regex(@"[A-Za-z]{3}"); //this will only return 2 matches
MatchCollection  matches = regex.Matches(input);
```

How should I get the following matches using regex?

```
abc
abc
bcd
```

Is this possible, if not will LINQ help this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String input = "abc12345abcd";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[A-Za-z]{3}");
int i=0;
while(i<input.Length){
    Match m=regex.Match(input,i);
    if(m.Success){
        Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
        i=m.Index+1; //just increment one char, instead of length of match string
    }else break;
}
```

Results

```
abc
abc
bcd
```

Comment: a follow question: what if I will have a regex [A-Za-z]{3,} how can get same results like abc abcd bcd

Comment: Yes, `[A-Za-z]{3,}` will give you `abc abcd bcd`, its mean 3 characters and above will match

Comment: if i have this string "passingx" i want to get all possible words(substring) i.e. passing passin passi pass pas assingx assing assin assin assi ass ssingx ssing ssi singx sing sin ing ingx ing ngx respectively can this be done on a single regex exp? thanks

Comment: [A-Za-z]{3,} will not return the result because it starts after the next match, if will increment i by 1 every iteration i will duplicate results when the loop encounters a non alpha chars.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that, while not clearly documented, `Matches` returns **non-overlapping** matches -- so the second match for `abc` means there's nothing returned for `bcd`, as it would be overlapping.

To get overlapping matches, you can program a loop calling the [Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx) (singular) method to get one match object at a time; as long as the match object has the `Success` property as true, you keep looping with the second argument to the `Match` method being one more than the [Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.index.aspx) property of the previous match object (to get the next match whether overlapping or not).